# Getting google assistant to respond in another language

Tags: response, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I've set up an app/agent in google's Dialogflow.
I've gotten my assistant to talk to it, and perform Web-hooks to a service that i've set up.

The user talks to the google assistant in English, the service Google is talking to, essentially just randomizes a swedish word, and presents it back as text to speech in swedish.

For instance, "Ok Google, talk to testapp today's word." and google responds with "Dagens ord: köttfärs".

However, the google voice speaking back to the user, is stuck in English and I can't seam to change it to Swedish response. I want the app to listen in English, but respond in Swedish if that makes sense, it's a training exercise for english friends to learn swedish words.

I found some API documentation mentioning `locale`, so I tried fiddling with it but that seams to be bound to the client/agent's source language determaining the outcome voice..

Here's the response data *(in python format)*:

```py
response_headers = {}
response_headers[b'Content-Type'] = b'application/json'
response_headers[b'Google-Assistant-API-Version'] = b'v2'

response_data = {
    "fulfillmentText": TTS,
    "locale" : "sv-SE",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "card": {
                "title": TTS,
                "subtitle": TTS,
                "imageUri": "https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "text": "Turn it off",
                        "postback": "https://service.com/google_home.py?state=off"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "source": "service.com",
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": False,
            "locale" : "sv-SE",
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": TTS,
                            "locale" : "sv-SE"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the assistant that it should switch language context on reply, not depending on input? Adding `locale` above seamed to do very little so I guess I'm way off here?

I should perhaps mention that `TTS` is the phrase `"Dagens ord: köttfärs"` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no directly supported way to have the Assistant reply in a different language than the conversation is setup for (which is what it expects the input to be).

For simple things, instead of using text-to-speech, you can [use SSML to play pre-recorded audio](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#audio). Something like

```
   <speech>
     <audio src="https://example.com/audio/dagens-ord-kottfars.mp3">
       <desc>Dagens ord: köttfärs</desc>
     </audio>
   </speech>
```

If you needed this to be more dynamic, you create another webhook that takes the text that you want and uses something like [Google's text-to-speech API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio) to create an mp3 audio. You can then provide this URL as the src of the audio. (Unfortunately, Google doesn't seem to allow for data URLs either.)

Comment: (And yes, before you say it, I agree, I wish they'd support multi-lingual responses already.)

Comment: Great workaround to be honest, introduces some lag obviously but that's acceptable. Yea I wish they supported this, since they have the ability to. But for now, good workaround and you have my thanks!